# How to tell if a Github repository is an R package

Tags: r, git, search, github

My goal is to create an R function (or set of R functions) to search Github (possibly via [the search API](http://developer.github.com/v3/search/), or some other way) that identifies R packages available at Github. This would mimic R's `available.packages()` functionality but for development versions of packages (not) on CRAN.

I thought this would be easy. It seems it is not.

One can start by searching for all repositories that use the language R. [The result](https://github.com/search?q=language%3AR&ref=simplesearch) is some 8,199 repositories. But many of these are not R packages and instead are books, courses, or just miscellany. I would like to be able to feed the search results into `devtools::install_github` function and this will obviously fail miserably on things that are not actually packages.

So, is there any way to identify whether a Github repository is an R package? My intuition is to be able to identify packages by their distinguishing characteristics:

- /R and /man directories
- DESCRIPTION file
- NAMESPACE file
- others?

But I'm lost as to how to do this. Obviously, one could download each repository (like `devtools::install_github` does and then check to see if it's a package, but that seems excessive).

Any insights? (I'm not necessarily looking for a complete solution here.)

Comment: https://github.com/hadley/r-on-github

Answer (score 1):

#### You can parse github pages of repos.

All you need is a parsing library for language you prefer. I never did it in R (commonly, I use Python) but I think you will find something. If R tools for parsing wiil be not enough convenient you can use another language to parse data and R to process it.

#### How to parse.

Url of your search request is

`https://github.com/search?p=1&q=language%3AR&ref=simplesearch&type=Repositories`

Then look at pagination block.

```
<span class="disabled prev_page">◀</span> 
<span class="current">1</span> 
<a href="/search?p=2&amp;q=language%3AR&amp;ref=simplesearch&amp;type=Repositories" rel="next">2</a> 
<a href="/search?p=3&amp;q=language%3AR&amp;ref=simplesearch&amp;type=Repositories">3</a> 
<a href="/search?p=4&amp;q=language%3AR&amp;ref=simplesearch&amp;type=Repositories">4</a> 
<a href="/search?p=5&amp;q=language%3AR&amp;ref=simplesearch&amp;type=Repositories">5</a> 
<a href="/search?p=6&amp;q=language%3AR&amp;ref=simplesearch&amp;type=Repositories">6</a> 
<a href="/search?p=7&amp;q=language%3AR&amp;ref=simplesearch&amp;type=Repositories">7</a> 
<a href="/search?p=8&amp;q=language%3AR&amp;ref=simplesearch&amp;type=Repositories">8</a> 
<a href="/search?p=9&amp;q=language%3AR&amp;ref=simplesearch&amp;type=Repositories">9</a> 
<span class="gap">&hellip;</span> 
<a href="/search?p=99&amp;q=language%3AR&amp;ref=simplesearch&amp;type=Repositories">99</a> 
<a href="/search?p=100&amp;q=language%3AR&amp;ref=simplesearch&amp;type=Repositories">100</a> 
<a href="/search?p=2&amp;q=language%3AR&amp;ref=simplesearch&amp;type=Repositories" class="next_page" rel="next">▶</a></div>
```

You can get the page number here (100) using parsing selectors. Then you can parse all repos titles and links for them. They looks like

```
<h3 class="repolist-name">
    <a href="/hadley/devtools" class="css-truncate css-truncate-target">hadley/devtools</a>
</h3>
```

Using the url and changing pages from 1 to max you can obtain all repos and links. Then take a look at repo page. For ex., we are looking for NAMESPACE.

```
<td class="content">
    <span class="css-truncate css-truncate-target"><a href="/hadley/devtools/blob/master/NAMESPACE" class="js-directory-link" id="7347fe5a0f184f79ef064e92e3beb297-5343453e5cabfcbdea6f829e232c6f994af44719" title="NAMESPACE">NAMESPACE</a></span>
</td>
```

Just search though css-class "js-directory-link" and you can find out lots of stuff.

The last thing to do is to make some kind of logic that will make a desicion!